# How to declare a global variable in Javascript using Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

Js file inside I have a function with a particular algorithm.

For reading xml file and transform the data to variable name wordData.

Inside the function has the following line of code:

```
var wordData = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName (Node1);
```

I can not set the variable "wordData as a global" outside the function or global
Inside the function

```
function language() {
    lang = "heb";
    if (lang == "heb") {
        thisWord = wordArrayHeb[indeXML];
    }
    else {
        thisWord = wordArrayEng[indeXML];
    }
    alert("language thisWord:=" + thisWord);
}


function setWord() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            if (xhr.responseXML) {
                var wordData = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(Node1);
                XMLength = wordData.length;
                for (i = 0; i < XMLength; i++) {
                    wordArrayHeb[i] = wordData[i].getElementsByTagName(Node2)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    wordArrayEng[i] = wordData[i].getElementsByTagName(Node3)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }
                language();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

**the variable thisWord is effected from varible wordData which is not global.**
Outside the functions, varible thisWord is empty
inside the function is ok and it has a value.

Would love help.
Thank you!

Comment: I changed my answer, i think it should fit you better

Answer (score 2):

Simply declare

```
var wordData;
```

outside the function and change your line to:

```
wordData = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName (Node1);
```

Hence removing the var declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global var anywhere in JS by using the window object:

```
window['wordData'] = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(Node1);
```

or

```
window.wordData = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(Node1);
```

Then wordData can be accessed globally.  This may not be the best solution for your problem, consider using function arguments and return values instead.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working. if any one can help me plz I will appreciate thx. my skype centerWow

Answer (score 0):

i think setting it as a global var is not the best choice, if you wish to access wordData inside the function language, you should pass it as a parameter like so:

```
language(wordData);
```

and in declaring function language(), just make it so it accepts the parameter:

```
function language(wordData) {
...
}
```

Comment: my code  http://centerwow.com/ajax/ajax1/wordData.rar if you sucasses You will see the word "Eric" below the input serch. Thanks

Comment: Sort of an antipattern because these can be harder to track down, and usually not scoped the way they are intended